# SVN Pre-Commit hook to check all .php files for svn:keyword Id

Tags: svn

I want to create a pre-commit hook that checks all php files if they have the svn:keyword "Id" set. Unfortunately, I have no idea how. Google doesn't really help me either.

Can anyone help me with this, maybe an example script to get me started?

Thanks!